# cronjob not able to access config.ini when running python3 script

Tags: python-3.x, cron, configparser

I have a crontab entry which is running a python3 script. This python script uses a config.ini file to get some tokens for use in the script.

The crontab entry is:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /opt/scripts/tf_state_backup/tf_state_backup.py >> ~/cron.out 2>&1
```

The config.ini file has the following:

```
[terraform]
token = <base64 encoded API key>

[gitlab]
token = <base64 encoded API key>
```

The relevant part of the python script is as follows:

```
import configparser

## read config file and decode api keys
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.abspath('config.ini'))

tfc_token = base64.b64decode(config['terraform']['token']).decode('utf-8')
gitlab_token = base64.b64decode(config['gitlab']['token']).decode('utf-8')
```

When this runs I can check the cron.out file for any errors. I get the following error every time it runs.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scripts/tf_state_backup/tf_state_backup.py", line 17, in <module>
    tfc_token = base64.b64decode(config['terraform']['token']).decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'terraform'
```

I have checked the following:

- Ensured script and config has correct permissions & +x permission
- Ran script exactly as it is in the cron tab, it runs fine without any problems
- Ensured the config.ini was being referenced by it's absolute path, not relative path

Any help on this would be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Your should use the `get` method of `ConfigParser` object. The first parameter is the section name the second is the variable name. If the `raw` parameter is set to True then special characters will be read as string (Eg.: `%`).

I have written a working version.

**test.ini:**

```
[terraform]
token = aGVsbG93b3JsZA==

[gitlab]
token = bm90X2hlbGxvd29ybGQ=
```

**test.py:**

```
import configparser
import base64

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("test.ini")

tfc_token = base64.b64decode(config.get('terraform', 'token', raw=True)).decode('utf-8')
gitlab_token = base64.b64decode(config.get('gitlab', 'token', raw=True)).decode('utf-8')

print(tfc_token)
print(gitlab_token)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
helloworld
not_helloworld
```

**FYI:**

- I have used `Python3.6.6` and `Linux` OS for testing.
- I have generated the base64s on this site: https://www.base64encode.org/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this running by updating the cron job to the following:

```
*/15 * * * * cd /opt/scripts/tf_state_backup/ && /usr/bin/python3 /opt/scripts/tf_state_backup/tf_state_backup.py
```

I am perhaps not getting the path correctly for the config file?

Regardless it is now working.